# How to enable Rubymine 5's spreadsheet feature by default?

Tags: text, csv, rubymine

In opening up a client's .txt file (was pretty much a multi-line CSV file though) in Rubymine, two tabs appeared at the bottom, Text and Data. The Data tab had the data loaded in a spreadsheet and froze the top row for scrolling. Very cool, but I have no idea how to replicate it. I have a bunch of similar client files (labelled .txt but are CSVs) and only some of them do the spreadsheet view. There's nothing discernibly different about these files as compared to others from what I see. I can't find anything on JetBrain's website...or any other site for that matter about this feature. Nothing in the Help section or the Preferences. Anyone encounter this before?

Comment: There are some issues related to this feature, for example [line breaks can disable the data display](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101408). You should file a bug with a sample file to reproduce the problem.